# Colour cells by named colour using gt package in R

Tags: r, gt

I have a table of data with colour names next to each item. I would like to change the cell colour of either colA or the colC to the colour specified. My preferred output for tables is using gt package. For example:

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

df<- tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB, ~colC,
  "apple",   1, "green",
  "banana",   2, "yellow",
  "cherry",   3, "red"
)

gt(df) |>
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(font = system_fonts(name = "monospace-code")),
    locations = cells_body()
  ) |>
  cols_width(everything() ~ px(100)) |>
  tab_options(table_body.hlines.style = "all") |>
  cols_align("center") |>
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "gray95"),
      cell_borders(sides = c("l", "r"), color = "gray50", weight = px(3))
    ),
    locations = cells_body(columns = colB)
   )
```

How can I use the colour info in the table to colour cells. I tried to copy the [example using hex codes in gt reference](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_style.html#examples) (see image below) but couldn't get it to work, even the example code was throwing up an error for me.

[image: gt reference example].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`from_column`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_style.html?q=from_column#using-from-column-with-cell-styling-functions) helper function with `cell_fill` which allows

> to get parameter values from a specified column within the table.

Hence, using `from_column` you can pass the colors from your `colC` column to the `color=` parameter of `cell_fill`.

```
library(gt)

df |>
  gt() |>
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(font = system_fonts(name = "monospace-code")),
    locations = cells_body()
  ) |>
  cols_width(everything() ~ px(100)) |>
  tab_options(table_body.hlines.style = "all") |>
  cols_align("center") |>
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = from_column(column = "colC")),
      cell_borders(sides = c("l", "r"), color = "gray50", weight = px(3))
    ),
    locations = cells_body(columns = colB)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: OK my mistake: I had tried "from_column" without any success - but I just realised I was using gt 0.9. After updating this works perfectly, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is another option (not very efficient), using the hex codes to change manually the rows.

```
gt(df) |>
  cols_width(everything() ~ px(100)) |>
  tab_options(table_body.hlines.style = "all") |>
  cols_align("center") |> 
  # This is the second column first row: color green
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#3CB44B"),
      cell_borders(sides = c("l", "r"), color = "gray95", weight = px(3))
    ),
    locations = cells_body(columns = colB, rows = 1)
  ) |> 
  # This is the second column second row: color yellor
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#FFE119"),
      cell_borders(sides = c("l", "r"), color = "gray95", weight = px(3))
    ),
    locations = cells_body(columns = colB, rows = 2)
  ) |> 
  # This is the second column third row: color red
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "#E6194B"),
      cell_borders(sides = c("l", "r"), color = "gray95", weight = px(3))
    ),
    locations = cells_body(columns = colB, rows = 3)
  )
```

[image]